# program is not taking in input even when I want it to

Tags: c, input, integer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int F = printf("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
  int C = (F - 32) / 1.8;
   printf("%i", C);

}
```

output:

> Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: 0

I want to create a program which easily converts Fahrenheit to degree Celsius so the output should be

> Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: (number given by user)
> (degree Celsius)

Comment: You need to add some kind of input... try `char buf[100]; if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); F = strtol(buf, 0, 10);` between your definition of `F` and `C`. (The prototypes for `exit()` and `strtol()` are in `<stdlib.h>`)

Comment: If you want to take input, then you need to use a function that does that.

Comment: `printf` is an output function, not an input function.  The value it returns is the number of characters written, which probably isn't what you want for `F`.

Comment: Your **C programming book** should have an example on how to read input from user, using for example `scanf`. If you don't have a book then now would be a good time to get one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `printf` is only for outputting formatted strings and returns the number of characters printed if the call is successful.

Consider using `scanf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int F = 0;
  printf("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
  scanf("%d", &F);
  int C = (F - 32) / 1.8;
  printf("%i\n", C);

}
```